# How to make a string the value of two other strings?

Tags: php

Pretty basic question, but my method looks super duper messy and wondering if there's any other way of achieving this that looks cleaner?

```
$title = 'Post title Goes Here';
$author = 'Post author Goes Here';
$post_title = ''.$title.' - '.$author.'';
```

How can I make `$post_title` not look so ugly? But serve the same purpose?

Comment: What do you expect from the string content? What does mean for you "not look so ugly?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `$post_title = $title.' - '.$author;` you actually don't need the first and last quote group.

Answer (score 2):

```
$post_title = "$title - $author";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use an array and implode.
This keeps your variables "grouped together" and usually makes it easier to code.

```
$post["title"] = 'Post title Goes Here';
$post["author"] = 'Post author Goes Here';

$post_title = implode(" - ", $post);
// Or to keep it grouped:
$post["post_title"] = implode(" - ", $post);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). From the docs:

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

```
$post_title = "$title - $author";
```

If you want to concatenate your variables with a `-`, you could use single quotes:

```
$post_title = $title.' - ' .$author;
```

You can also use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to return a formatted string.

```
$post_title =  sprintf("%s - %s", $title, $author);
```